# Why does synaptic package manager not open on i3 window manager?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, 16.10, synaptic, i3-wm

I am running Xubuntu Yakkety and using the i3 window manager. Thus far, all the GUI applications I needed were accessible from the dmenu and opened correctly.

However, the synaptic package manager GUI does not open when I launch it from the dmenu. It works fine when I have a xfce session, so it looks like the problem is isolated to i3 session. I have not customised the i3 config file beyond the vanilla one created by the i3-config-wizard when first launching an i3 session.

Why is synaptic not launching on the i3 window manager ?

Comment: Do you get any error messages, if you try to open `synaptic` from a terminal instead of  `dmenu`?

Comment: Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.